# Grub menu won't show after installation (two-disk)

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, windows-7

I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and installed it on a 115GB partition next to a 15GB swap alongside Windows 7.

I'm using a asus g73s.

I have 2 drives: one with only Windows (500GB) and another with a partition for (250GB) Windows and (115GBb) the Ubuntu and (15GB) swap partitions.

But after the installation, I can't find out how to run Ubuntu. It just run windows.
I read that it should show a grub menu.

I tried:

- Holding both <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys at boot up.
- Running the Ubuntu Live CD and edit the grub file.
- Also pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> and some function button during boot.

Nothing seems to work.

---

I solved my problem.

I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> during boot and a boot menu opened and there i choosed option: P2 and than the grub menu showed.

Comment: I am confused when you say next to a swap file for Windows 7. Is it a 2 hard drive set-up, or 1 drive with 2 partitions. I ask this because when you install grub will set up well, but to set up a dual boot with either OS on different physical drives can be done without grub (boot from menu or BIOS), It is a different than a multi-boot from various partitions on one physical drive (in my limited experience)

Comment: I have 2 drives. One with only windows (500gb) and another with a partition for (250gb) windows and (115gb) the ubunto and (15gb) swap partitions.

Comment: I find it difficult to press or hold the shift button at just the right time. You might try this over and over. Repeated pressing of "shift" has sometimes worked for me. This may depend somewhat on the BIOS installed in the machine. Be sure the BIOS setting is adjusted to boot from the drive with Ubuntu on it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem.

I  pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> during boot while showing the BIOS prompt and a menu opened with options for booting from available hard disks and there I choose option: P2 (The second hard disk) and then the grub menu showed.